# How to fix the future >= 0.15.2 distribution not found

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

On Fedora 27 when I run `cookiecutter` https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django I get:

```
File "/usr/bin/cookiecutter", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3038, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3022, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3051, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 657, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 971, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 857, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'future>=0.15.2' distribution was not found and is required by cookiecutter
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1582746):

> `python-cookiecutter-1.6.0-3.fc27` has been pushed to the Fedora 27 testing repository.
>
> See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Updates_Testing for
> instructions on how to install test updates.